# How to map an int value to a String value

Tags: java

How would someone be able to map int values 1, 2 and 3 to a String, so it would output "Small (300)", "Medium (600)" and "Large (1200)"?

```
public static int newPackageDeal(String msg, String error) 
{
    int packageDeal;   

    do 
    {   
        System.out.println(msg);                   
        packageDeal = in.nextInt();                   
    }
    while (packageDeal != 1 && packageDeal != 2 && packageDeal != 3);

    return packageDeal;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: @JBNizet should have gone for Switch over if

Comment: @Christian simplest things first.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `switch` statement:

```
String output;
switch (packageDeal) {
    case 1:
        output = "Small (300)";
        break;

    case 2:
        output = "Medium (600)";
        break;

    case 3:
        output = "Large (1200)";
        break;

    default:
        output = "NA";
}
```

If you had a longer term need in your program to map deal integers to strings, you might store these relationships in a database table, and then populate a map somewhere in your Java code.  Then, you could just lookup string descriptions whenever you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashMap to store the output value against the the number.

```
HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
map.put(1,"Small (300)");
map.put(2,"Medium (600)");
map.put(3,"Large (1200)");
```

Then simply return the output value based on the packageDeal inside newPackageDeal() method.

```
public static String newPackageDeal(String msg, String error) 
{
    int packageDeal; 

    do 
    {   
        System.out.println(msg);                   
        packageDeal = in.nextInt();                   
    }
    while (packageDeal != 1 && packageDeal != 2 && packageDeal != 3);

    return map.get(packageDeal);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put you deals in a Map, index by the number.

This is more extendible than using `if/else` of `switch` statements, and your `while` condition becomes clearer.

```
public static String newPackageDeal(String msg, String error)
{
    Map<Integer, String> dealsByNumber = new HashMap<>();
    dealsByNumber.put(1, "Small (300)");
    dealsByNumber.put(2, "Medium (600)");
    dealsByNumber.put(3, "Large (1200)");
    // Easy to extend with other deals later on!

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int packageDeal;

    do
    {
        System.out.println(msg);
        packageDeal = in.nextInt();
    }
    while (!dealsByNumber.containsKey(packageDeal));

    return dealsByNumber.get(packageDeal);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but for some reason it is still outputs an integer :/